# Using %S Outside of Sprintf in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, string-literals

In working with ldap code in php, I came across code which featured usage of %s, both within and outside of an sprintf line.  Here's the link to the original code:
https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592
To what do the %s in the second and third examples (below) refer?
Thanks for any leads.

Here are the places it was used:

First - this is how I usually see %s used - with sprintf:

```
if ( ! call_user_func_array ( 'ldap_bind', $args ) ) {
    // Binding to the LDAP Server for querying the LDAP failed.
    // This can be one of many reasons.
    die sprintf(
        'Could not bind to server %s. Returned Error was: [%s] %s',
        $host,
        ldap_errno($_connect),
        ldap_error($_connect)
    );
}
```

The second and third examples (below), however, are what has me stumped.

second:

```
if (! isset($filter)) {
    $filter = '(&(uid=%s)(objectClass=posixAccount))';
}
```

third:

```
$filter           = str_replace('%s', $trimmerdUsername, $filter);
```

Comment: That's just templating and they chose to use `%s` as the placeholder.  It could have been `{uid}` or `*s*` or anything.

Comment: You assign a string variable with `%s`? This may come as a surprise but you can do the same in an array `["%s", "hello world"]`

Comment: That looks like they just used `%s` for string replacement. It could have been anything, like: `"$filter = "here foo"; $filter = str_replace('foo', 'replace-with-this', $filter);`. That would return `"here replace-with-this"`. In `str_replace()`, the `%s` has no special meaning. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php